# Apply h:outputScript to a h:panelGroup and not to the whole jsf page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2.2

I have a jsf page on which whole panels are clickable even when there is a link inside the panel. This is done by applying the following js function to the jsf page.(Please note the page structure)

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="col-md-3">
    <h:form>
        <ui:repeat> 
            //lots of panels and panel groups   
        </ui:repeat> 

        **<h:outputScript>
            $(function() {
                setupPanelLinks();
            });
        </h:outputScript>**    

    </h:form>    
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup id =**"SeceondPanelGroup"** layout="block" styleClass="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
</h:panelGroup>
```

where the js function is on another seperate .js page

```
function setupPanelLinks() {
    $(".panel").click(function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).find("a.myLink").attr('href');
    });

    $(".panel a").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

where myLink is a styleClass that is applied to a h:link inside the ui:repeat of the first .

Now every thing works fine. The problem is that the javascript function is applied to all the panels in the jsf page where as i want to apply it to only the upper panel group and not to the "SecondPanelGroup". My JS knowledge is limited but i am guessing we need a target for the js function to narrow down its scope. Any suggestions how it can be achieved?

**Can a javascript function be applied to a certain part of the page e.g div and not to the whole page?**

Comment: Javascript is applied client side, net serverside, so the generated html instead of the xhtml is relevant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can a javascript function be applied to a certain part of the page e.g div and not to the whole page?**

Yes, javascript function can do that. In your case, the function is applied to the whole page or lets say to all the panelGroups because in your function `setupPanelLinks()`, you use `(".panel")` which is how panelGroups are rendered in html.

On the panelGroups that you want to apply it, give them an id (if they are more than one, give them a styleClass as an id can not be repeated in the same jsf page) and use this id/styleClass in you function instead of `(".panel")` .e.g.

```
function setupPanelLinks() {
    $(".clickablePanel").click(function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).find("a.myLink").attr('href');
    });

    $(".clickablePanel a").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```